# comparing two equal strings in python gives false

Tags: python, string

I was trying to compare two similar string (representing hash) in python. expected the result to be true but surprisingly it gives out result as false. any idea why is it so?

```
 res = '2f5a9ad9cca4be62a84ab6c9a6e5a274ea44f72f3fc6b7228bfbf8ff91977370 ' ==  [ '2f5a9ad9cca4be62a84ab6c9a6e5a274ea44f72f3fc6b7228bfbf8ff91977370'] 
 print(res)
```

Comment: A list with a string isn't a string. I would be surprised if that comparison gave true

Comment: ^that, and also the first string has a empty space at the end

Comment: they are not equal. Even if you remove '[' and ']' they will not be equal. The first string has a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not comparing two strings.  You are comparing a string with a list.  Try:

```
res = '...' == ['...'][0]
```

or

```
res = ['...'] == ['...']
```

(Where the ... is the string you are comparing.)

Comment: the former solution works . A very basic question, how can I convert 'word' to ['word']

Comment: @HoneyKhandelwal def a list and then do `list.append('word')`

Comment: @HoneyKhandelwal if you have `res = 'word'` you can do `res = [res]`

Answer (score 0):

A list containing a string is not equal to the string.

```
x = ('nep' == ['nep'])
print(x) #false
```